# Why does ssh-agent have SGID set?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, redhat, ssh-agent

In the openssh Red Hat package, I noticed that the `ssh-agent` executable has the SGID permission set:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ssh-agent
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root nobody 113648 Nov 24  2010 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
```

Why would the openssh developers want `ssh-agent` to run with the `nobody` group? Or maybe I am misunderstanding what SGID does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, mine's setgid to the `ssh` group.  I'm guessing you're on a RedHat-derived system; they love to abuse the `nobody` user/group.

A bit of googling suggests that the setgid is to prevent a security vulnerability whereby secret key material is obtained by ptracing the agent (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.ssh/59).  Making the process setgid-anything means that ptracing by non-root (or at least non-`CAP_SYS_PTRACE`) users is EPERMed.

Comment: Thank you for leading me the right direction. Appreciate it.

Comment: Why the group ownership of ssh-agent is noboby not root?

Comment: @AskandLearn: Because if it runs SGID root, it has root-equivalent powers, and so any vulnerability in `ssh-agent` would suddenly be a root-level vulnerability -- which would be very, *very* bad.